# BibTeX suddenly failed mysteriously

Tags: bibtex, miktex

This is my first question here. I have a problem that bibtex just suddenly failed me. I get the following error message in the console but it doesn't help me much. What does "This operation is supported only when you are connected to the server" mean?

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: biblatex_ex.aux
>   The style file: biblatex.bst
>
> bibtex.EXE: Windows API error 1251: This operation is supported only
>   when you are connected to the server.
>
> bibtex.EXE: Data:
>   \dustaff\home\kss\Documents\PaperI\texbib:bibPaper1.bib texify:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex.EXE" failed for
>   some reason.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE so other people can try this?

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure that this is the kind of problem that will be helped with a minimal example. Kristin, try changing the MikTeX update settings to point to a different update source and see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: I can give you the code and see if you can compile it, but my main interest is to know if anyone else recognize this error-message.

Comment: This might not be the solution to your problem but worth a shot! There might be a new entry in your bibliography file with a bad formatted url. If this is the case, remove/correct it, then **clean *all* the auxiliary files** and try again. Might not solve the problem but again, could be helpful.

Comment: @Pouya You are the angel of the day! When I go back in my mind, I think the error occured when I added a new entry with an url. I'm quite new to BibTex so I don't know all it's mysterious ways yet... Big thanks!

Comment: @pouya Great troubleshooting job! Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Happy it helped. I will add it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

There might be a new entry in your bibliography file with a badly formatted `URL` field. First locate such entry and correct the url field (or remove it if you're not interested in urls).

Then clean all the *auxiliary files* and try again.

P.S. When downloading `bibtex` entries from conferences and journals websites, one has to be careful about the way they have formatted them. As an example `IEEE` have their own style and if you are not using that style, the resulting bibliography might be unexpectedly problematic!